# How to write jasmine test to check update

Tags: unit-testing, testing, coffeescript, jasmine

I'm trying to write jasmine test to check is view changing time or not

```
it 'ticks the time', ->
  @time = parseInt($('#timer h1').text())
  setTimeout (->
    @after = parseInt($('#timer h1').text())
    expect(@time).toBeLessThan(@after)
  ), 1000
```

The problem is that when time of `setTimeout` is up the `jasmine` is already finished his job, no html code on page related to this test at that moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jasmine already has solutions for this kind of task:

```
it 'ticks the time', ->
  runs ->
    @time = parseInt($('#timer h1').text())
  waits(1000)
  runs ->
    @after = parseInt($('#timer h1').text())
    expect(@time).toBeGreaterThan(@after)
```